# window.open loads popup page completely after executing logic

Tags: javascript

I am trying to popup aspx page using window.open in parent page

```
 var win = window.open("apConfirmInvoiceSubmit.aspx");
    win.focus();
    hWnd =window['rturn'];
    if((hWnd == 1) || (hWnd == 2))
     {
     document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnInvoiceSubmit").value = hWnd;    
     document.getElementById("ctl00_btnOK").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("btnattach").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("txtAref").innerHTML="";
     document.getElementById("ctl00_txtWait").style.display = "";                       
     return true;
 }
```

In child page

```
function SendValue(i)
{

window.opener['rturn'] = i;

window.close();
}
```

Window.open failed to popup immediately. It popups after executing complete logic and returning undefined for the first time

Would appreciate anyone please help me with this issue.

Please let me know if my explanation is not clear or if more information is required

Comment: add a `load` event listener to your popup window?

Comment: @Kaiido - Actually window.open returns undefined value in chrome and firefox. Tried all the examples in goolge but not success. Can you suggest me how to proceed forward